# Risks of prolonged use of ultrasonic speakers

Tags: hearing, noise-induce-hearing-harm

I would like to know if there are known risks for hearing or any other possible health issue in case of long usage of ultrasonic (parametric) speakers (see an [example](https://www.soundlazer.com/product/sl-01-open-source-parametric-speaker/)) at low volume.
For long usage I mean about 8 hours every day for years.

I found some medical articles, mostly dating a few years ago, some are optimistic some are on the "it depends" side. It is clear that high volume and very high frequencies can be harmful. I do not have the medical experience needed to understand if the concerns expressed on those articles can be applied to my scenario (low volume, 8 hours each day)

Here are the most optimistic articles:

- [anesthesiology.pubs.asahq.org](http://anesthesiology.pubs.asahq.org/article.aspx?articleid=1934478)
- [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4698603/)

Here the less optimistic:

- [Wikilectures](https://www.wikilectures.eu/w/Effects_of_Ultrasound)
- [NHS.UK](https://www.nhs.uk/news/medical-practice/calls-for-research-into-health-effects-of-ultrasound-exposure/)
- [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_ultrasonic_waves_have_any_negative_impact_on_humans2)

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Specifically, why would you think that low volume sound would be harmful?

Comment: @CareyGregory, I read some concern about possible risks for hearing or brain in case of long usage of ultrasonic speakers (caused by the kind of wave, despite of volume). I found them on audio related sites, as explanation of the nearly not existing offer of this technology for consumers; those articles were missing reliable scientific references. I did not find this kind of information on medical oriented sites, hence my question.

Comment: The articles you read expressing concern should be linked in your question. That's what we mean by "prior research."

Comment: For the NHS to report public areas having ultrasound at around 94 decibels is frightening to me. [A jackhammer is at 100 decibels](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/chemsafety/Training/PPETrain/dblevels.htm)